# Multiple checkbox information is displayed in another activity when checked

Tags: android, checkbox, android-activity, checkboxlist

Our problem is we need to make some kind of a menu where on the first activity there is a list of food with checkboxes.

What we wanted to do is when the `onClickmeal_ok` button is clicked, the information in the checkboxes that were checked will be displayed in another activity.

This is our .xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="#ffff"
tools:context=".MainMenu" >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="@string/dessertsmenu"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="27dp"
    android:text="@string/meal_ok"
    android:onClick="onClickmeal_ok" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/chkAutosave3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/chkAutosave1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/chkAutosave1"
    android:defaultValue="false"
    android:text="@string/peachcrumbbars"
    android:onClick="onClickpeachcrumbbars_ok"  />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/chkAutosave4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/chkAutosave3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/chkAutosave3"
    android:defaultValue="false"
    android:text="@string/snickerysquares"
    android:onClick="onClicksnicjerysquares_ok"  />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/chkAutosave1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:defaultValue="false"
    android:text="@string/blackberrypiebars"
    android:onClick="onClickblackberrypiebars_ok"  />
```

and this is our .java file:

```
package net.xadtv.yoursmenu;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
public class DessertsMenu extends Activity{
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.desserts);
}

public void onClickblackberrypiebars_ok(View view) {

}
public void onClickpeachcrumbbars_ok(View view) {

}
public void onClicksnicjerysquares_ok(View view) {

}
public void onClickmeal_ok(View view) {
    }
}
```

Comment: You will probably have a better chance of getting help if you provide the community with some insights of what the current problem with the code is. Do you get any error messages? If so, please update your question with it.

Comment: hmmm. there is no particular error on the codes. I just really want to learn and know how to display a TEXT or detail of the checkbox in a next activity when a checkbox is checked and the "ok" button is clicked. Let's say the checkbox name is pudding, then it is checked then "ok" button is clicked. So "pudding" text should show in the next activity :)

Answer (score 0):

To pass data between activies use Intent extra,

```
public void onClickmeal_ok(View view)
{
Intent i = new Intent("com.example.activityname");
i.putExtra("extra1", "this is an extra");
i.putExtra("extra2", 420);
}
```

You can also use Bundle to put multiple items at once

```
public void onClickmeal_ok(View view)
{
Intent i = new Intent("com.example.activityname");
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putInt("extra4", 420);
i.putExtras(extras);
}
```

Then you can retrieve data by using

```
String stringExtra1 = getIntent().getString("extra1");
```

or retrieve the whole bundle with

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks. But what can we add on the new .xml file where we'll show the checked checkbox?

Example first checkbox name is coke and second checkbox name is pepsi. If coke is checked we want the new .xml file to display:

List of Orders:
Coke

Sorry we're really new on this stuff ^^

Comment: I would do this in the OnCreate method of the second activity's .java file, retrieve your extras and check your values then load the list with whatever you need